Codeigniter 4 ajax post results in 404 error
I am trying to handle a form submit using the JQuery ajax function on localhost xampp. However, the following always results in a 404 page not found error:
$(document).on("click", ".iconsTop .iconst", function (e) {
    var idfilter = $(this).attr("id");;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "text",
      url: "filter",
      data: { filter_id:idfilter },
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {
        $('.maincontact').empty().append(data);
      }
    });
  });

Controller:
class App_home extends BaseController
{
    public function filter()
    {
        echo 'ok';
    }
}

Router
use CodeIgniter\Router\RouteCollection;
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);
$routes->get('filter', 'App_home::filter');

After submitting the form, I always get the following error in Google Chrome's page inspector:

jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2  POST http://localhost/app/public/filter 404
(Not Found)
404 Controller or its method is not found: Filter::index


change the POST URL into http://localhost/filter

Did you check whether this is a JS problem or a PHP problem? Does the URL look like the others from your application?

Your route seems to only match a GET request but your ajax request uses the POST method.

This address 'http://localhost/app/public/filter' works fine separately, but don't work in Ajax js

The ajax request type is POST but your route seems to be defined as GET. Change the type of your ajax request to GET or change your route to POST.
    $(document).on("click", ".iconsTop .iconst", function (e) {
    var idfilter = $(this).attr("id");;
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "text",
      url: "filter",
      data: { filter_id:idfilter },
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {
        $('.maincontact').empty().append(data);
      }
    });
  });

